# Why gdal_calc.py only work in terminal but nothing happened using PHP exec or Python script?

Tags: php, python, gdal

I have a simple command using gdal_calc that only works directly in the mac terminal. But, when I run in PHP using exec or in python, nothing happened.

I have a simple code like this :

`gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"`

In PHP:

```
exec('gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"', $output, $response);
```

this doesn't do anything so i run it direclty using python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.call('gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"', shell=True);
```

no error and no result. When i use `gdal_grid` or `gdalwarp` it works well in both languages